# Family of Lie algebras parametrized by a discrete valuation ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, etale-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology

I have a family of Lie algebras parametrized by a discrete valuation ring, whose generic fiber is reductive and whose special fiber is nilpotent. I'd like to learn about the relationship between the cohomology of the special fiber and the cohomology of the generic fiber. In particular, I have good reason to believe that a certain part of the cohomology of the special fiber is isomorphic to the cohomology of the generic fiber.

Are there any results related to Lie algebra cohomology that can help with my situation ? More generally, I'd like to know about results related to how cohomology varies from the special fiber to the generic fiber for varieties over a discrete valuation ring. Everything I've found is related to mod-$p$ étale cohomology, but I'd really like to know about results related to Lie algebra cohomology.

Thank you!